# Implication with each other

Tags: logic

If

$$a \implies b, c \implies b$$ then what axiom/property states $$a \implies c$$ ?

I am thinking this is true, but unable to verify. Help?

Comment: This is not true in general as written. If you have $a\implies b$ and $b\implies c$ then you have $a\implies c$ by transitivity.

Answer (score 5):

This isn't *always* true, see the following counter example -

$$\text{Dog} \rightarrow \text{Animal}$$
$$\text{Cat} \rightarrow \text{Animal}$$
But
$$\text{Dog} \color{red}{\nrightarrow }\text{Cat}$$

Answer (score 3):

It's not true in general that $a$ implies $c$.

For instance, let $b$ be the statement "$n$ is even", $a$ the statement "$n$ is divisible by $4$" and $c$ the statement "$n$ is divisible by $6$".

Answer (score 1):

This is not true. Suppose $a$ is the statement "$n=2$", $b$ is the statement "$n$ is even", and $c$ is the statement "$n=4$". Then we clearly have $a \Rightarrow b, c \Rightarrow b$, but it's certainly not true that $a \Rightarrow c$.

However, if you modify your claim we can make it true.
Suppose $a \Rightarrow b, b \Rightarrow c$. Then we have $a \Rightarrow c$.

Answer (score 1):

Not quite! See [truth table](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=truth%20table(%20(a%3D%3Eb%20)%26(%20c%3D%3Eb))%3D%3E%20(a%3D%3Ec)). $(A\implies B) \land (C\implies B)\implies (A\implies C)$ is false only when $A$ is true, $B$ is true and $C$ is false. Otherwise, it is true.